# equivalent command for gnumake (for...do, if exist,del)

Tags: shell, makefile, cygwin, gnu-make

I'm converting a makefile so it can be used with gnu make. In the other make program (can't find what was the version...) this part was executed :

```
#******************************************************************************
#                                Explicit Rules
#******************************************************************************
#
# This section contents the explicit rules to create the Virtual File system.
# This file system actualy contains the files used by the Web interface.
# 
#******************************************************************************
CFGFILE = $(WEBDST)/vfs.cfg

# Compiling vfsdata
$(OBJDIR)vfsdata.o : vfsdata.c
    @echo .
    @echo ::.   COMPILING1 : vfsdata.c
    @echo ::::.
    $(NOECHOC)$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DEBUGFLASG) $(subst \,/,$(VFSDIR))/vfsdata.c -o"$@"     $(INCLUDE)


# Dependance of vfsdata.c
vfsdata.c : $(addprefix $(WEBSRC)\,$(WEBGLOBAL)) $(addprefix $(WEBDST)\,$(WEBLOCAL))

# Make vfsdata.c writable
    @if exist $(VFSDIR)\vfsdata.c \
            chmod 777 $(VFSDIR)\vfsdata.c

#
# Generate the configuration file needed by vfscomp
#
    @echo [general] > $(CFGFILE)
    @echo vfs_root_dir  = $(WEBDST)>> $(CFGFILE)
    @echo vfs_data_file = $(VFSDIR)\vfsdata>> $(CFGFILE)
    @echo vfs_image_var = vfsimage>> $(CFGFILE)
    @echo far_pointer   = yes>> $(CFGFILE)
    @echo compress      = yes>> $(CFGFILE)

    @echo [file] >> $(CFGFILE)
    @echo $(sort $(WEBGLOBAL) $(WEBLOCAL)) | $(TR) -s " " "[\n*]" \
                                       | $(SED) "s/gif/gif -u/g" \
                                       >> $(CFGFILE)

#
# Create the local directory tree
#
    @for %%f in ($(subst /,\,$(dir $(WEBGLOBAL)))) do \
            if not exist $(WEBDST)\%%f mkdir $(WEBDST)\%%f

#
# Copy the WEB pages directory tree localy
#
    @for %%f in ($(subst /,\,$(WEBGLOBAL))) do \
            cp -rf $(WEBSRC)\%%f $(WEBDST)\%%f

#
# Generate the virtual file system
#
    @$(TOOLDIR)/vfscomp $(subst \,/,$(CFGFILE))

#
# Delete the local directory tree
#

#delete the directory recursively exept the one in the exclusion list

    @for %%f in ($(filter-out $(EXCLUSION), $(WEBDIR))) do \
            if exist $(WEBDST)\%%f \
                    rm -rf $(WEBDST)\%%f

#delete the remaining files.

    @for %%f in ($(subst /,\,$(WEBGLOBAL))) do \
            if exist $(WEBDST)\%%f \
                    rm -f $(WEBDST)\%%f

    @del $(subst /,\,$(CFGFILE))
```

When I build my code, I get this error

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

I have the feeling that some commands like @for @del @if exist are command that are not supported(or with a different syntax) in the gnu make.

I checked in the online GNU make documentation but I didn't found commands that are similar to those used below.

Is there any equivalent in gnu make to the command used in this part of the makefile?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT :

I removed the @ and executed make. I can see when the message "The syntax of the command is incorrect" appear :

```
if exist ../Pa/Filesys\vfsdata.c \
    chmod 777 ../Pa/Filesys\vfsdata.c
echo [general] > ../Pa/Filesys/vfs.cfg
echo vfs_root_dir  = ../Pa/Filesys>> ../Pa/Filesys/vfs.cfg
echo vfs_data_file = ../Pa/Filesys\vfsdata>> ../Pa/Filesys/vfs.cfg
echo vfs_image_var = vfsimage>> ../Pa/Filesys/vfs.cfg
echo far_pointer   = yes>> ../Pa/Filesys/vfs.cfg
echo compress      = yes>> ../Pa/Filesys/vfs.cfg
echo [file] >> ../Pa/Filesys/vfs.cfg
echo behavior/datasync/datasync.htc behavior/defered/defered.htc behavior/inputs/indirect.htc behavior/inputs/inputs.htc behavior/progress/progress.htc behavior/slider/slBottom.gif behavior/slider/slLeft.gif behavior/slider/slRight.gif behavior/slider/slTop.gif behavior/slider/slider.htc css/env.css html/cfgmain.html html/changepass.html html/diagpa.html html/firmhlp.html html/firmware.html html/home.html html/logpage.html html/progressend.html html/progressstart.html html/soundhlp.html html/support.html html/uplmain.html html/uploadstart.html img/button.gif img/logo.gif index.html xslt/activate.xslt xslt/main.xslt xslt/netmenu.xslt xslt/page.xslt xslt/page_func.xslt xslt/progress.xslt xslt/tlmenu.xslt xslt/upload.xslt | tr -s " " "[\n*]" \
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
                                       | sed "s/gif/gif -u/g" \
                                       >> ../Pa/Filesys/vfs.cfg
for %%f in (.\ css\ img\ img\ xslt\ xslt\ xslt\ xslt\ xslt\ xslt\ xslt\ xslt\ html\ html\ html\ html\ html\ html\ html\ html\ html\ html\ html\ html\ behavior\slider\ behavior\slider\ behavior\slider\ behavior\slider\ behavior\slider\ behavior\datasync\ behavior\progress\ behavior\inputs\ behavior\inputs\ behavior\defered\) do \
```

It appear that the syntax error is somewhere on the line

```
echo $(sort $(WEBGLOBAL) $(WEBLOCAL)) | $(TR) -s " " "[\n*]" \
                                       | $(SED) "s/gif/gif -u/g" \
```

Comment: Prepending @ to a command is only a signal to make to not echo the command as it is executed. You should add all relevant context as to _where_ the error is generated.

Comment: did you examined `cmake`? if it is not a big project it can be easy to port `cmake`.

Comment: For what it's worth, the Makefile is already in GNU make syntax, and will not work with other Makes. See MadScientist's answer for more.

Comment: @selman I will check cmake, but as I can read, it seems that I have more a shell problem than a make problem...

Comment: As a debugging aid, you might want to remove the leading @ signs so that you can see which command is failing.  Might as well leave it that way; you can run with `make -s` if you want quiet operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will take a few iterations (especially since you haven't given us a complete sample).

There are two rules here; try them separately.

Try the second rule with only the first command:

```
# Make vfsdata.c writable
        @if exist $(VFSDIR)\vfsdata.c \
            chmod 777 $(VFSDIR)\vfsdata.c
```

Let us know the results of these experiments, and we'll go from there.

**EDIT:**

Interesting. I'd guess that either `tr` doesn't like your syntax, or the length of that command has exceeded some limit of your Make or OS.

Try doing it from the command line:

```
echo behavior/datasync/datasync.htc behavior/defered/defered.htc behavior/inputs/indirect.htc behavior/inputs/inputs.htc behavior/progress/progress.htc behavior/slider/slBottom.gif behavior/slider/slLeft.gif behavior/slider/slRight.gif behavior/slider/slTop.gif behavior/slider/slider.htc css/env.css html/cfgmain.html html/changepass.html html/diagpa.html html/firmhlp.html html/firmware.html html/home.html html/logpage.html html/progressend.html html/progressstart.html html/soundhlp.html html/support.html html/uplmain.html html/uploadstart.html img/button.gif img/logo.gif index.html xslt/activate.xslt xslt/main.xslt xslt/netmenu.xslt xslt/page.xslt xslt/page_func.xslt xslt/progress.xslt xslt/tlmenu.xslt xslt/upload.xslt | tr -s " " "[\n*]" \
| sed "s/gif/gif -u/g" \
>> ../Pa/Filesys/vfs.cfg
```

If that succeeds, it's a Make length limit; try with fewer file names.
If it fails, try omitting the last term:

```
echo blah blah blah \
| sed "s/gif/gif -u/g"
```

Tell us the results, and we'll proceed...

Comment: I only put was I think is the relevant part of the make file that have a problem, the makefile is big to put in a message... (the rules are elsewhere in the makefile)

Comment: I noticed in the output that I got some path with \ and / in them. ex. In the make file I have **if exist $(WEBDST)\%%f** with **WEBDST=../Pa/Filesys** give : **../Pa/Filesys\%%f** . I put $(subst \,/,$(foo)) where the slash where not backslash and I don't get syntax error anymore.

Comment: Yes. I think I will mark your answer, you where on the good path to help me find my problem.

Answer (score 2):

To be clear, none of the commands you mention are make commands.  They are all shell commands. Make is invoking a shell and passing those commands to the shell.  As mentioned elsewhere, the "@" is a special command to make (supported by all POSIX-based make implementations including GNU make) that tells make to not print the command before sending it to the shell (the "@" is removed by  make before sending the command to the shell).

Second, the error message "the syntax of the command is incorrect" is not anything GNU make ever prints.  Either you have paraphrased the error message rather than repeating it verbatim (never a good idea when asking for help), or that message is being printed not by make but by some shell command that make invokes.

Comment: Do you wish to port this to a Unix shell (Bourne or bash) or some other dialect of Windows than it was originally written for?

Comment: I made a direct copy and paste of the error I get when I run make. @tripleee , I'm not in a Unix shell, I'm working in a windows OS, I should have add this detail when I first written my question.

Comment: I also have cygwin installed (for sed and tr for example)